# Metaspace leak using LambdaMetaFactory

Tags: java

I have a code like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, LambdaConversionException {
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    while (true) {
        Class<?> declaringClass = MyClass.class;
        Class<?> propertyType = List.class;
        String methodName = "getCustomerList";
        LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
                "apply",
                MethodType.methodType(Function.class),
                MethodType.methodType(Object.class, Object.class),
                lookup.findVirtual(declaringClass, methodName, MethodType.methodType(propertyType)),
                MethodType.methodType(propertyType, declaringClass));
    }
}


public static final class MyClass {

    public List<String> getCustomerList() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

As you can see, this is an endless loop which calls `LambdaMetafactory.metafactory`. It doesn't store anything, not even the resulting `CallSite`. Yet, very quickly, I get:

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Compressed class space
```

I've done a heap dump and - as expected - there is nothing in the heap that I would expect to cause this. In fact, Eclipse Memory Analyzer Tool doesn't have any suggestions for me as to what could be leaking.

For a better visual view of what's happening, this is the chart of loaded classes provided by VisualVM:

[image: It only goes up]

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-17.0.7+7 (build 17.0.7+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-17.0.7+7 (build 17.0.7+7, mixed mode, sharing)
```

How does this metaspace leak happen, and what can I do to prevent it?

EDIT: As suggested in the comments, adding `System.gc()` to the loop slows the issue down significantly. The classes are still loaded without being unloaded, but suddently metaspace grows *much slower*. When I ran this for 10 minutes, it didn't get past 50 MB, whereas before I would get OOP in seconds. That said, metaspace still grows indefinitely and the app will eventually get the OOM.

(I find this behavior even stranger; why would calling `System.gc()` slow down this leak so much, yet normal running of the app - which also gets full GC every now and then - doesn't seem to affect the leak much?)

Comment: My guess is that the hidden classes do not get unloaded for some reason. Even though they *can* be unloaded in this case, there is no such *requirement* in the [spec](https://openjdk.org/jeps/371). Calling `System.gc()` seems to prevent it.

Comment: In my experience, `System.gc()` slows it down, but it does not stop. It now takes much longer to get to the OOM, hours instead of seconds, but it gets there anyway. it is good to know that the class need not be unloaded - but then the only way for my app to survive is to not use this API.

Comment: Confirmed on JDK 20 on Mac. This might be a bug.

Comment: @kittylyst I'd love to report it, but unless I missed something, the OpenJDK bug tracker is only accessible to people "with OpenJDK Author status or above". Might you perhaps be one of those people?

Comment: Potentially related jdk bug report https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8302154 (thanks Aleksey)

Comment: @LukášPetrovický You can't directly submit to [JBS](https://bugs.openjdk.org/projects/JDK/issues/JDK-8305968?filter=allopenissues) without an account, but you can submit via https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/. Though based on the link by Geoffrey, anything you report may be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior appears to be due to a [bug in the JDK](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8302154).
At the time of writing this answer, there was no fix.