# OptaPlanner how to get LambdaMetafactory access

Tags: optaplanner

I noticed this is OptaPlanner's logging output:

```
[TRACE] [2023-09-24 17:25:14,657] [main] [o.o.c.i.d.s.d.SolutionDescriptor]     Model annotations parsed for solution MySolution:
[TRACE] [2023-09-24 17:25:14,658] [main] [o.o.c.i.d.s.d.SolutionDescriptor]         Entity MyClass1:
[TRACE] [2023-09-24 17:25:14,658] [main] [o.o.c.i.d.s.d.SolutionDescriptor]             Genuine variable interval (pretty fast access with LambdaMetafactory)
[TRACE] [2023-09-24 17:25:14,658] [main] [o.o.c.i.d.s.d.SolutionDescriptor]         Entity MyClass2:
[TRACE] [2023-09-24 17:25:14,659] [main] [o.o.c.i.d.s.d.SolutionDescriptor]             Shadow variable events (slow access with reflection)
```

Why would one class get pretty fast access and the other get slow access? What are the requirements to get pretty fast access for a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Timefold](https://timefold.ai/blog/2023/optaplanner-fork), the LambdaMetaFactory accessors no longer exists - it was causing a [metaspace memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76593538/metaspace-leak-using-lambdametafactory). Also, the reflection access is no longer called "slow" - it is the fastest accessor possible with the supported APIs of the JDK, and the difference from the metafactory approach was negligible in our benchmarks.